# How to fetch the specific key value inside the collection using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

Given below command giving the output as object

$output = (Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmname -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath authoring.ps1).value

```
 Output
```

---

```
Mode             : Process
ContextDirectory : 
ContextFile      : 
CacheDirectory   : 
CacheFile        : 
Settings         : {}

Code          : ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded
Level         : Info
DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
Message       : @{cluster_name=test01; status=green; timed_out=False; number_of_nodes=3; 
              number_of_data_nodes=3; 
              active_primary_shards=25; active_shards=50; relocating_shards=0; 
              initializing_shards=0; 
              unassigned_shards=0; delayed_unassigned_shards=0; number_of_pending_tasks=0; 
              number_of_in_flight_fetch=0; task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis=0; 
              active_shards_percent_as_number=100.0}
 Time          : 
 Code          : ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded
 Level         : Info
 DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
```

How to get the Message ==> number_of_nodes = 3  and number_of_data_nodes=3 in some variable so based on this value I need to perform some action.
Thanks

Comment: What does `$output.Message.GetType()` reveal?

Comment: `$output.Message.number_of_nodes` Should give you what you need

Comment: @TristanOtterpohl Its not working only working $output.Message and giving the specific data but inside the Message there is multiple key pair value

Comment: $Output = gc E:\Result.txt 
foreach($temp in $Output)
{
    if($temp -match "node")
    {
        [int]$number_of_nodes=(($temp -split ";")[3]-split "=")[1]
        [int]$number_of_data_nodes=(($temp -split ";")[4]-split "=")[1]
    }
}
$number_of_nodes
$number_of_date_nodes         '''  This code is working when I am copying this output in  some text file. but when I am directly work with $output then its not working

Comment: @Theo , IsPublic = True , IsSerial = True , Name = String and BaseType = System.Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if as you tested `$Output.Message` is a multiline **string** like

```
@{cluster_name=test01; status=green; timed_out=False; number_of_nodes=3; 
              number_of_data_nodes=3; 
              active_primary_shards=25; active_shards=50; relocating_shards=0; 
              initializing_shards=0; 
              unassigned_shards=0; delayed_unassigned_shards=0; number_of_pending_tasks=0; 
              number_of_in_flight_fetch=0; task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis=0; 
              active_shards_percent_as_number=100.0}
```

you can convert this into a Hashtable like this:

```
$data = $Output.Message.Trim("@{}") -replace ';', [environment]::NewLine | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

If you print that out to screen with `$data | Format-Table -AutoSize` it looks like this:

```
Name                             Value 
----                             ----- 
number_of_nodes                  3     
task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis 0     
number_of_data_nodes             3     
status                           green 
initializing_shards              0     
active_shards_percent_as_number  100.0 
cluster_name                     test01
delayed_unassigned_shards        0     
active_shards                    50    
unassigned_shards                0     
active_primary_shards            25    
number_of_in_flight_fetch        0     
timed_out                        False 
relocating_shards                0     
number_of_pending_tasks          0
```

With this Hashtable format, it is easy to get the values of the different keys.
For instance:

```
$data.number_of_nodes            # --> 3
$data.number_of_data_nodes       # --> 3
$data.cluster_name               # --> test01
```